# NameError: name 'attach_and_send_screenshot' is not defined** in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

used to sent attachment through selenium, using `self._attach_and_send_screenshot()` funtion to autogenertation.

**Enter anything after scanning QR code
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "wht.py", line 21, in 
    attach_and_send_screenshot()
NameError: name 'attach_and_send_screenshot' is not defined**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, StaleElementReferenceException, ElementNotVisibleException
from urllib.parse import quote_plus

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://web.whatsapp.com/')

all_names = ['Anas Cse']
msg = 'testing'
count = 1

input('Enter anything after scanning QR code')

for name in all_names:
    user = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[@title = "{}"]'.format(name))
    user.click()

    msg_box = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2S1VP')

    for i in range(count):
         self._attach_and_send_screenshot()
#         msg_box.send_keys(msg)
#         button = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2lkdt')
#         button.click()



def _attach_and_send_screenshot(self):
    # TODO - ElementNotVisibleException - this shouldn't happen but when would it

    # local variables for x_path elements on browser
    attach_xpath = '//*[@id="main"]/header/div[3]/div/div[2]/div'
    send_file_xpath = '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/div/span/div/div/div[2]/span[2]/div/div'

    if self.attachment_type == "img":
            attach_type_xpath = '//*[@id="main"]/header/div[3]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/ul/li[1]/input'
    elif self.attachment_type == "cam":
        attach_type_xpath = '//*[@id="main"]/header/div[3]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/ul/li[2]/button'
    elif self.attachment_type == "doc":
        attach_type_xpath = '//*[@id="main"]/header/div[3]/div/div[2]/span/div/div/ul/li[3]/input'

    try:
        # open attach menu
        attach_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(attach_xpath)
        attach_btn.click()

        # Find attach file btn and send screenshot path to input
        time.sleep(1)
        attach_img_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(attach_type_xpath)

            # TODO - might need to click on transportation mode if url doesn't work
        attach_img_btn.send_keys(os.getcwd() + "/screenshot.png")           # get current script path + img_path
        time.sleep(1)
        send_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(send_file_xpath)
        send_btn.click()

                # close attach menu
        time.sleep(1)
        attach_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath(attach_xpath)
        attach_btn.click()

    except (NoSuchElementException, ElementNotVisibleException) as e:
        print(str(e))
        send_message((str(e)))
        send_message("Bot failed to retrieve search content, try again...")

def send_message(msg):
    whatsapp_msg = driver.find_element_by_class_name('_2S1VP')
    whatsapp_msg.send_keys(msg)
    whatsapp_msg.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Comment: Where is your `except` block?

Comment: File "wht.py", line 61

                              ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Comment: Your `try` block should be followed by `except` block

Comment: can you please have a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

move the function definitions before your main logic.  You are trying to call a function that has not been defined yet